# Ensure each solr node/instance has at max one leader in a given solr cloud

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I was working on Solr cloud POC , how is the performance of solr cloud, if  solr node has two shards vs single shard.

For two shard per node case , single solr/instance has two leaders (as each node has two shards). Which is causing some issues during the NRT.

So in my test I want to ensure that "each solr node/instance has at max one leader in a given solr cloud".

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by calling two API calls in sequential

> 1. /solr/admin/collections?action=BALANCESHARDUNIQUE&collection=polaris&property=preferredLeader
> 2. /solr/admin/collections?action=REBALANCELEADERS&collection=polaris .